# Is there any way to check whether IndextoString assigns the same values while using labels from StringIndexerModel

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I have spark dataframe with two target classes for column **status("Placed","Not Placed")**.

I used **StringIndexer** to convert the above column to indices in a pipeline and executed it.

> str_indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol=status,outputCol="status_index").fit(df_train).transform(df_train)

**It assigned these values - **{0: 'Placed', 1: 'Not Placed'}****

used IndextoString to convert the prediction label generated from the RandomForest algorithm to String again and used the labels generated from the above StringIndexer(str_indexer)

> IndexToString(inputCol="prediction",outputCol="status",labels=loaded_model.stages[0].labels).transform(in_indexed)

1. Is this the correct way to convert the indices back to strings?
2. Does the above IndextoString assigns the same values i.e., 0 for "Placed" and 1 for "Not Placed" ?
3. Is there any way to test whether IndextoString assigns the same values as StringIndexer

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the correct way. To check the mapping you can try after transforming your dataframe using IndextoString as

```
df.select('status','prediction').distinct().show()
```

This will give you the mapping

Comment: Hi Raghu, In normal cases IndextoString uses metadata of the column to assign the labels. In the above scenario I'm explicitly providing the labels to IndextoString, so is there any way to check how IndextoString is assigning the values?

Comment: You are fetching the label list from the stored model right? then the mapping will be the same as you used in the training. To make sure, try the code in my answer. Then you wil get as 
````  status   prediction
       placed       1
       not placed   0
````